# VS2013 new file as committed status with GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

This is my git url : https://github.com/Kation/Wodsoft.Net

Open it with vs2013, Add a new code file to any project

the file status change to committed and there is no commit menu

use "git status" command also show no file change

Only this git has this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this

I have no idea why that vs2013 add all project path into .gitignore file

So all the changes in projects are all ignored

Comment: It doesn't look like it did that.  It looks like the `.gitignore` that it created (which is the very reasonable default one at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) was modified and committed on Jun 14 and again on Jun 15.

Comment: I never change .gitignore manual. And it always works good in other projects so I don't check this file when commit it...